# Magento 2 - How to show product grid in my custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, frontend, product-grid

> I created a custom module,in that module I want to display product
>   listing grid based on selection I want to do some different operations
>   for selected product in frontend.Can anyone help me how to show
>   product listing grid (like product listing showing in admin product
>   page).